# How to escape colon in EL?

Tags: jsp, el

We are using 3rd-party tool which provide request parameter as `"A:B","A:C","A:D"` where A is service(TOOL TERMINOLOGY) and B,C,D is parameter.

How to access variable using EL?
If i am providing `${param.A:B}`, it throws exception. Even i tried with `${param.'A:B'}`.

Note: We are avoiding scriptlet as much as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Use `${param['A:B']}`. This is an alternative to dot notation in the expression language.